# TSQL - Appending text to a datetime in the SELECT gives unwanted order of operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, operator-precedence

I have a query:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    Person.Name AS PersonName,
    YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100 AS JustCenturyNumbers,
    Person.PersonNumber AS RestOfDateTimeNumbers,
    YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100+Person.PersonNummer AS CompleteDateTimeNumber
FROM Person
```

What I want is to append the RestOfDateTimeNumbers to JustCenturyNumbers and get a complete datetime number representation like:

```
PersonName  JustCenturyNumbers  RestOfDateTimeNumbers   CompleteDateTimeNumber
Tim         20                  0003167012              200003160000                
Fred        19                  0009272725              190009270000                
Jenny       19                  0106207228              190106200000
```

But what I get is:

```
PersonName  JustCenturyNumbers  RestOfDateTimeNumbers   CompleteDateTimeNumber
Tim         20                  0003167012              3167032
Fred        19                  0009272725              9272744
Jenny       19                  0106207228              106207247
```

I guess that the /100-function is somehow applied to the rest of the string somehow rather than the date alone, but I've been unable to solve it as I'm new to TSQL-functions.

Any idea of how I can fix this and get the result I want?

I use TSQL and SQL-Server 2008 (rt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're falling foul of [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190309(v=sql.100).aspx) when doing the concatenation. You need to [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) the first part of your formula to varchar if you want the final result to be treated as text rather than numeric:

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    Person.Name AS PersonName,
    YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100 AS JustCenturyNumbers,
    Person.PersonNumber AS RestOfDateTimeNumbers,
    CAST(YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100 AS varchar(2)) +Person.PersonNumber AS CompleteDateTimeNumber
FROM Person
```

Answer (score 2):

in your query you are adding two int values

change it to string concat by casting values to varchar

```
SELECT TOP 3 
    Person.Name AS PersonName,
    YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100 AS JustCenturyNumbers,
    Person.PersonNumber AS RestOfDateTimeNumbers,
    cast(YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100 as varchar(2))+cast(Person.PersonNummer as varchar(16)) AS CompleteDateTimeNumber
FROM Person
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a derived table (nested SELECT), it's real easy.

```
SELECT 
t.*, 
cast( JustCenturyNumbers as varchar(50) ) + 
cast( RestOfDateTimeNumbers as varchar(50) )  
as CompleteDateTimeNumber
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 3 
    Person.Name AS PersonName,
    YEAR(Person.DateBorn)/100 AS JustCenturyNumbers,
    Person.PersonNumber AS RestOfDateTimeNumbers,
    FROM Person 
) t
```